# Div appear on image click

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm fairly new to **jQuery** and I havent' been able to solve this. Here is the code I am trying:

```
$('img.mobile_menu_button').click(function() {
    $('.mobile_menu_list').css('visibility', ($('#show').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
});
```

I just want a div to appear when I click on an image. Shouldn't be hard, but I just can't get it to work.

FIddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/muWLG/5/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It appears..... and BTW where's your `$('#show')` element?

Comment: Yep appears for me as well.

Comment: Your fiddle works! What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'd only add a class to .mobile_menu_list:

```
$('.mobile_menu_button').on('click', function() {
    $('.mobile_menu_list').addClass('is-active');
});
```

And in your CSS:

```
.mobile_menu_list.is-active {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

If you do not need CSS visibility, but could also rely on display:

```
$('.mobile_menu_button').on('click', function() {
    $('.mobile_menu_list').show();
});
```

And in your CSS:

```
.mobile_menu_list { display: none; }
```

Comment: Why pollute CSS and JS with extra classes when `toggle()` or `show()` is enough

Comment: In the CSS mobile_menu_button is not defined as display:none, but visibility:hidden. A toggle() or show() will not do the trick here. I am not sure if -instead of using visibility- display could be used.

Comment: `visiblity : hidden` is a mess, cause on absolute positioned elements will not allow you to click an anchor underneath. So instead of blindly look at what the OP has I would suggest to think about using show() **and `display property` in CSS**

Comment: Today is not my day. I've tried to get that working everywhere, and it didn't work. You guys point out that it works, and lo and behold...lol. 

Can anyone suggest how I could make it toggle? Its for a mobile menu, so I can't just have it staying there if somebody lets go. :D

Roko in answer to your question, I "pollute" stuff because I have no idea what I am doing. CSS I am fine with, and photoshop and I are best friends. But Jquery...not so much.

Thanks for all the help though, you guys are awesome.

Comment: Adding a class might be very powerful and useful, since you can use it for children elements in a DOM as well. I cannot judge based on the given context if visibility can be skipped, for display. If so, it definitely has an advantage and should be used.